# how to route any downloaded file to error channel when DB is down and how to process them after DB is up?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I have implemented polling in my springboot application.This code checks remote directory at regular interval and downloads any new file from remote directory.After the file is downloaded we process the file and save the data in Database.Suppose if database is down my processed file data is not saved in DB .Whenever DB is up again my file is not picked up for processing and hence the file data is not saved.I read on net that if i am able to route the file whose data couldn't be saved in DB to an error channel then whenever DB is up the file will get processed

Below is my code which downloads the file

```java
@Bean

  Properties configProperties(){

Properties config = new Properties();

config.setProperty("PreferredAuthentications", "password");

            return config;

        }

@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)

    public PollerMetadata pollRemoteDirectory() {

        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();

        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(
                new PeriodicTrigger(getSftpConfig().getPollingInterval(), TimeUnit.MINUTES));

        pollerMetadata.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(1000);

        return pollerMetadata;

        }

    @Bean

    SftpInboundFileSynchronizer syncRemoteFilesToLocalDirectory() throws MalformedURLException {

        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSync = new VsSftpInboundFileSynchronizer(getSftpConfig().sftpSessionFactory());

        fileSync.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);

        fileSync.setRemoteDirectory(getSftpConfig().getRemoteFilePath());

        CompositeFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> compositeFileListFilter = new 
        CompositeFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>();

        compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));

        fileSync.setFilter(compositeFileListFilter);

        return fileSync;

    }

@Bean

    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "sftpChannel")

    public MessageSource setMessageSourceAndLocalDirectory() throws MalformedURLException {

        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
                syncRemoteFilesToLocalDirectory());

        source.setLocalDirectory(new File(getSftpConfig().getArchiveFilePath()));

        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);

        return source;
    }

@Bean

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")

    SftpFileHandler messageHandler() {

        return new SftpFileHandler();

    }

@Bean

    public static ResourceBundleMessageSource emailMessageSource() {

        final ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasename("mail/MailMessages");

        return messageSource;

    }

@Bean

    public static SpringTemplateEngine emailTemplateEngine() {

        final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(textTemplateResolver());

        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());

        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(stringTemplateResolver());

        templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(emailMessageSource());

        return templateEngine;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem that polled files are stored in the internal  `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` for the `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource`.

You need to configure an external bean like this:

```
@Bean
public FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter localFilefilter() {
    return new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "sftpFiles");
}
```

Then inject it like this:

```
 source.setLocalFilter(localFilefilter());
```

The when an exception happens form the file storing into the DB, you just need to call a `delete()` method of that filter with the file you can't store. See `ResettableFileListFilter`:

```
/**
 * A {@link FileListFilter} that can be reset by removing a specific file from its
 * state.
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 4.1.7
 *
 */
public interface ResettableFileListFilter<F> extends FileListFilter<F> {

    /**
     * Remove the specified file from the filter so it will pass on the next attempt.
     * @param f the element to remove.
     * @return true if the file was removed as a result of this call.
     */
    boolean remove(F f);

}
```

I may guess that your `SftpFileHandler` does that hard work, so you can configure an `adviceChain` for its `@ServiceActivator` with an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and configure its `failureChannel` to perform the mentioned `delete()` operation.

This way an unprocessed file is going to be polled from SFTP again on the next poll cycle.

Another way to achieve the goal is to use a *retry*. For this purpose you can utilize a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` for the same `@ServiceActivator.adviceChain()` reason. In this case the same file will attempt to be stored in DB again and again, without any required error handling logic.

See more info in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#message-handler-advice-chain and also: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#recovering-from-failures-2

Comment: To configure an adviceChain for  @ServiceActivator with an ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice and configure its failureChannel to perform the mentioned delete() operation---This approach will require IntegrationFlow right?Is there other way where i can avoid IntegrationFlow?

Comment: That's not. There is just enough a `@ServiceActivator` for that `failureChannel`